# Installing app on a Sandbox, Not through AppExchange

Tags: appexchange

How can I install an app on a Salesforce Sandbox, but not through the **AppExchange**?

I mean like in *Android* we install apps from *Google play* but we can also install an app from an *APK* file

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way of installing from github/heroku, I think that's how I installed the meta data app from Andrew fawcett

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, its possible to install a custom application from an alternate source than app exchange.

Following are different options:

1. [Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging):

   - Developers can distribute links of their managed or unmanaged packages (custom apps), without publishing them to appexchange. Using this links admins can install the application in any Developer/Sandbox/Production orgs.
2. Using source code with any [deployment tool](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/alm_deployment/units/alm_tools):

   - Apart from packages, developer can share their source code/SRC file which can be deployed to any org with help of [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_pro_deploy.htm), [Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench) or [ANT deployment tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm).
3. [Deploy to Salesforce button](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/09/24/deploy-direct-from-github-to-salesforce/):

   - Deploy to Salesforce button in GitHub is also quite popular.